# Selenium, Element is not clickable at point while browser scrolls to this element

Tags: python, selenium

everyone.

I have code in python where I want to click at the element that is located near the end of page:

```
wait.until(visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='do-import']")))
wait.until(element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='do-import']")))

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='do-import']").click()
```

I'm using ChromeDriver.

When launching this script, it scrolls to this element and then crashes with this message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (500, 1707)
```

I though maximizing window size will help, but it won't.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first scroll till bottom with the below code:

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```

the try to click:

```
wait.until(element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='do-import']"))).click()
```

But make sure that we have unique `1/1` entry in **HTMLDOM:**

```
input[name='do-import']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `css selector` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

or if that does not work, try with `ActionChain`:

**Code trial 1:**

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
wait.until(element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='do-import']"))).click()
```

**Update:**

As mentioned you need to basically scroll till end of the page to let Selenium have the web element in its viewport.

And then trigger Javascript command using `execute_script` like below:

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", wait.until(element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='do-import']"))))
```

Comment: `webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).perform()` thows to me `Message: move target out of bounds`

Comment: however, this element exists and it is unique

Comment: What about scrolling till end of page ? `driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")` and then triggering `click` ?

Comment: Please see `Code trial 1:`

Comment: Well, it scrolled to bottom, but still thrown `Element is not clickable at point`.  The problem is that this element not quite at the bottom of the element. This page has very giant footer. When it scrolled at the bottom the button is not visible.

Comment: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", wait.until(element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='do-import']"))))` put this line after `driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")` and see if that helps

Comment: Now that worked. Could you update your answer and add some explanations how and why this is happening?

Comment: See above update section.